# laptop headphone jack problems

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, headphone-jack

A while back my headphones mysteriously started making static noise and one of them stopped working completely. At first I thought it was headphones so I bought new ones. Alas that did not solve the problem. The problem must be inside my headphone jack. I did some research online and they suggested unplugging USB devices. Which has a strange effect of changing the static noises to high frequency Morse code noises (it's the aliens).

I don't have this problem when i listen to music on speakers. The static is there on headphones whether there is music or not.

I own a soldering iron for electronics and I am quite skilled at soldering. I would appreciate any help I can get.

My laptop is the HDX 18. It has 2 headphone jacks that act exactly the same. 
Interesting thing i just noticed is that when i pull out my headphones almost all the way 
both of them start working but so do the speakers making the headphones kinda useless.

Maybe there is a way to turn of the speakers as a temporary solution.

I am using vista x64.

Comment: Its hp pavilion HDX 18.

Comment: today i turn on my computer and the static is completely gone (thats after months of there being static) and the other earphone started working. Strangest things are happening!

Comment: the problem keeps getting worse and better. Now both of the headphones work but there is noise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would check all the connections. Make sure there are no loose wires or shorts (wires or solder points that are connected when they shouldn't be).

If that fails you might try soldering in a new headphone jack.

Comment: Would also try reheating the current solder joints on the jacks.  It could be a "cold" joint resulting from heat and cool cycles.

Comment: it turns out it was my wireless card and its driver. For some reason even after I removed the wireless card problems would continue but now i had a new wireless card for a while and there are no more problems with sound